# Variadic template and default value with inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, variadic-templates

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int a;
    std::string b;
    A(int a_, std::string b_) : a(a_), b(b_) { std::cout << a << b << std::endl; }
};

struct B : public A {
    static const int VERSION=2;
    float c;

    template<typename ... ARGS>
    B(float c_, int v=VERSION, ARGS&&... args) : A(v, std::forward<ARGS>(args)...), c(c_) { std::cout << c << std::endl; }
};

int main() {    
    B(3.14, "abc");
}
```

Hi all, the compiler gives gives me template argument deduction/substitution failed error. How can I use a default value with a variadic template?

```
variadic.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
variadic.cpp:18:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B(double, const char [4])’
  B(3.14, "abc");
               ^
variadic.cpp:14:2: note: candidate: template<class ... ARGS> B::B(float, int, ARGS&& ...)
  B(float c_, int v=VERSION, ARGS&&... args) : A(v, std::forward<ARGS>(args)...), c(c_) { std::cout << c << std::endl; }
  ^
variadic.cpp:14:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
variadic.cpp:18:15: note:   cannot convert ‘"abc"’ (type ‘const char [4]’) to type ‘int’
  B(3.14, "abc");
               ^
variadic.cpp:9:8: note: candidate: B::B(const B&)
 struct B : public A {
        ^
variadic.cpp:9:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
variadic.cpp:9:8: note: candidate: B::B(B&&)
variadic.cpp:9:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Comment: Did you actually check to see if this was caused by inheritance? Because to me `A` 
 appears completely irrelevant. The problem exists solely in the signature of `B::B`.

Comment: You have `B(float, int, possibly_more_stuff)`.  `B(3.14, "abc");` does not match that

Comment: What did you expect from your `B(3.14, "abc")` ?

Comment: I expected that insert the default value for v, and call the base classs with a=2 and b="abc"

Comment: That's pushing SFINAE a bit further than it's designed to do. SFINAE: Substitution Failure Is Not An Error - You're probably not familiar with the term, but C++ has limited support for the concept you're assuming here. When trying to instantiate a function template, the C++ compiler will ignore instantiations that lead to errors in the _declaration_. Your example fails in the _definition_, however. The instantiation succeeds with `B::B(float, int)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if a function/method parameter has a default value, all following parameters must have a default value.

So

```
template<typename ... ARGS>
B(float c_, int v=VERSION, ARGS&&... args) 
   : A(v, std::forward<ARGS>(args)...), c(c_)
 { std::cout << c << std::endl; }
```

is wrong because there aren't default values for `args`.

Or better: you can write the following signature

```
B(float c_, int v=VERSION, ARGS&&... args)
```

but the default value for `v` is used only if you pass to the constructor only a value (`c_`) because `args...` is empty so `v` is the last parameter.

But if you want a some `args...`, the default value for `v` is ignored because, otherwise, the compiler can't know if a second integer parameter is the not-default value for `v` or the first `args...`

Comment: As a rule of thumb, your statement makes sense,  but function parameter packs (like these) are a [specific exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments). But since this question is exactly about this case, you can't ignore that exception.

Comment: @MSalters - you're right my initial aswer was very wrong expressed; I've tried to correct it.

Comment: I think it would be clearer to state it like this: "Default arguments allow you to call a function with **less** arguments than there are formal parameters. Function parameter packs allow you to call a function with **more** arguments than there are formal parameters. Since `B::B` has 2 arguments and 2 formal parameters, exactly equal, neither the default nor the parameter pack is used"

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your constructor can be called with one, two or more arguments.

If you call it with one argument, the second argument is defaulted.

If you provide two or more arguments, the provided default argument is not used. Your second argument is used, and it has to match the type of the second parameter.

Note that in general, you can achieve similar results by overloading a function instead of providing default arguments. In this case, I suspect that would give you the results you intend, but that's me guessing at your intents.

Comment: Amplifying this *specific* case, and a *specific* workaround, [something like **this**](https://ideone.com/igfLft) would work. That, assuming I guessed the same intent you did, and we're both soothsayers. =)

Comment: @WhozCraig - works but, IMHO, isn't a good idea: when I see the call `B(3.14f, 3, "xyz");` I have the doubt: the `3` is the version or the first `args...`? IMHO is better, from the point of view of the reader of the code, write the first constructor with version in first position: `B(int v, float c_, ARGS&&... args)`. So it's more clear that the `float` argument is ever the last before the variadic arguments.

Comment: @max66 Lest you have doubt, given those two template members, `B(3.14, 3, "xyz")` will *always* be a better match to the specified second `int` argument. That's simply (or not so simply) how the language works. That said, if someone wanted a second argument that was (a) `int`, and (b) *not* the version, they're screwed and there's not getting around that with just those two template members.

Comment: @max66: The reliable solution there is `B(3.14f, B::version{3}, "xyz")`. This require s a nested class `B::version`, but it very effectively solves ambiguities.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I know... I know... with "I have the doubt" I mean "I have to think a little about which constructor is used"; and I suppose it's the same form many C++ programmers. I just think that placing the version value in first position (in first constructor) make the calls simpler to read.